# wxpython - wx.EVT_COMBOBOX event and GetSelection method: manual vs user triggering

Tags: combobox, event-handling, wxpython, getselection

It is known that in wxpython setting in the code the value of a combobox doesn't trigger the EVT_COMBOBOX event as instead it does when the user select an item with the mouse. So, if needed, you have to trigger manually the event.

In my program, in the handler function, I need to use the value returned by the method event.GetSelection(), where event is the event object passed in to the handler function.

Now, the problem is that if I set in the code the value of the combo box and then trigger manually the EVT_COMBOBOX event, the method event.GetSelection() doesn't return the same value as if the event was rised by the user selecting the same item with the mouse.

The problem is shown by the following code.

As you can see executing the code, when the event is triggered by the code, the event.GetSelection() method returns always the value 0 (i.e. the first item in the combo box list, so that the item 'a' is displayed in the text box) instead of the value 1 setted in the code which would display the item 'b'.

Why this happen? Thank you for any answer.

```
import wx
class ManualEventFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Manual Event Rising',size=(550, 200))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.st=wx.StaticText(self.panel, label='Select an item', pos=(10,10))
        self.cb=wx.ComboBox(self.panel,pos=(110,10),choices=['a','b','c'])
        self.st2 = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label='You choosed item', pos=(10, 75))
        self.tc=wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,pos=(110,75))
        self.button = wx.Button(self.panel,label="Select item 'b' and rise\nmanually the EVT_COMBOBOX event", pos=(300, 40))

        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.onButton)
        self.cb.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.onSelect)

    def onSelect(self,event):
        self.tc.SetValue(self.cb.GetString(event.GetSelection()))
    
    def onButton(self, event):
        self.cb.SetSelection(1)
        myevent = wx.CommandEvent(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX._getEvtType(), self.cb.GetId())
        myevent.SetEventObject(self.cb)
        self.cb.GetEventHandler().ProcessEvent(myevent)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = ManualEventFrame(parent=None, id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `event.GetSelection` in this scenario continues to return `0` but the way around your issue, is to get the value from the "horse's mouth" so to  speak.
Use:
`self.tc.SetValue(self.cb.GetStringSelection())`
or:
`self.tc.SetValue(self.cb.GetValue())`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I bypassed the problem the same way you suggested me but I'm curious to know why that method behave so different. I don't know too much about creating events so maybe I forget someting.